# How to manipulate the properties of a user-defined class on runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, helpermethods

I have a huge **user-defined** class with lots of properties and some of them has to be set with a certain value.

To be more specific, all the **public properties** with the type of **string** in this **user-defined** class have to be *"emptied"* at the end of execution.

So i reached all the public properties one by one (like 300 properties) and assigned them with my 300 lines of code. What i did to solve this problem, did what i needed, but didn't satisfy me of course.

So i decided to write a **Helper Method** (as *Extension Method*) in C# that iterates through the properties of an object instance and access / manipulate them dynamically. I've seen some similar questions about iterating through properties in here, but didn't see anything about **changing property values** so far. Here is what i tried:

```
public static void SetDefaultStringValues(this Object myObject)
{
    PropertyInfo[] aryProperties = entityObject.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (object property in aryProperties)
    {
        if (property is String) 
        {
            //property = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

The commented part had to be the line that i set the variables but that wasn't really a success story :) I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PropertyDescriptor` of `System.ComponentModel` for lazy coding. Assuming you want to iterate over *public instance* methods (not statics) you can try the following sample:

**Test** *class*:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private int mIntMemeber = 0;                    // # to test int type   
    private string mStringMember = "abc";           // # to test string type (initialized)
    private string mNullStringMember = null;        // # to test string type (null)

    private static string mStaticNullStringMember;  // # to test string type (static)

    // # Defining properties for each member
    public int IntMember                            
    {
        get { return mIntMemeber; }
        set { mIntMemeber = value; }                
    }

    public string StringMember                      
    {
        get { return mStringMember; }
        set { mStringMember = value; }
    }

    public string NullStringMember
    {
        get { return mNullStringMember; }
        set { mNullStringMember = value; }
    }

    public static string StaticNullStringMember
    {
        get { return mStaticNullStringMember; }
        set { mStaticNullStringMember = value; }
    }
}
```

**SetDefaultStringValues()** *Extension Method*:

```
public static string SetDefaultStringValues(this TestClass testClass)   
{
    StringBuilder returnLogBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    // # Get all properties of testClass instance
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propDescCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(testClass);
    // # Iterate over the property collection
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in propDescCollection)
    {
        string name = property.Name;
        Type t = property.PropertyType; // # Get property type
        object value = property.GetValue(testClass); // # Get value of the property (value that member variable holds)

        if (t == typeof(string)) // # If type of propery is string and value is null
        {
            property.SetValue(testClass, String.Empty); // # Set value of the property (set member variable)
            value = String.Empty; // # <-- To prevent NullReferenceException when printing out
        }

        returnLogBuilder.AppendLine("*****\nName:\t{0}\nType:\t{1}\nValue:\t{2}", name, t.ToString(), value.ToString());
    }

    returnLogBuilder.AppendLine("*****");
    return returnLogBuilder.toString();
}
```

You could also check if **value** is *null* within the loop. `SetDefaultStringValues` method parameter could be any *object* instance. You can change it to `SetDefaultStringValues(this object o)` and use it as *extension method* for your defined class instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use PropertyInfo.SetValue method, more on this in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need a different syntax in order to check the property type; furthermore, you shold check that the property has a public setter.

```
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.GetSetMethod() != null)
    property.SetValue(entityObject, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in aryProperties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.CanWrite) 
        {
            property.SetValue(myObject, "", null);
        }
    }
```